# RFQuiltLayout Horizontal remove space from top and header

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

[image]I need to remove space from top and header and need to use full space in RFQuiltLayout collection view but i don't know how to do it.is there any property or delegate method to do??

Also i am not sure how to adjust size of cell as its going out of boundary how to fix it???

I have tried this

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)insetsForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);  //top, left, bottom, right
}
```

but did not help me